# Problemas con el uso de Robocopy

Tags: windows, cmd

Para copiar un archivo de un directorio a otro utilizo esta linea de comando

```
C:\>robocopy %userprofile%\desktop\db_doctor.sql D:\hi  /E /MT:24 /MIR
```

Y este es el error que manda al ejecutar:

> 2017/05/25 11:05:26 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Obteniendo acceso al
>   directorio de origen C:\Users\Byron\desktop\db_doctor.sql\ El nombre
>   de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta d
>   olumen no son correctos.

Answer (score 1):

El uso correcto de ***Robocopy*** para copiar es ficheros es:

```
robocopy c:\origen d:\destino nombre_fichero.sql
```